# Script field using expression - Only the member variable [value] or member methods may be accessed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use script fields in my query.
I enabled sandbox scripting, and trying to use an expression to calculate a new field.

The thing is I get the following error:

```
{
   "type": "expression_script_compilation_exception",
   "reason": "Only the member variable [value] or member methods may be accessed on a field when not accessing the field directly"
}
```

It seems that only "value" is accessible. what am I missing here?

When running the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields" : {
    "field1" : {
        "script" : {
            "lang": "expression",
            "inline": "doc['about.hobbies'].empty"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping:

```
{
  "my_index": {
  "mappings": {
     "type": {
        "properties": {
           "about": {
              "properties": {
                 "hobbies": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "lowercase"
                 }
              }
           }
        }  
     }
   }
}
```

Little explanation: I have a field which can contain list of string values.

```
"hobbies": ["a","b",c"]
```

and it can be also empty. I want to have a script field of type boolean that will have the value true when the list is not empty, and false when the list is empty.

**Update**: Reading some more, I encounter this documentation on [lucene expressions scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts)

> There are a few limitations relative to other script languages:
>
> - Only numeric fields may be accessed
> - Stored fields are not available
> - If a field is sparse (only some documents contain a value), documents   missing the field will have a value of 0

My field is of type String, it might be the problem?
If it is, is there any other way to use script fields based on string fields? maybe using groovy?

Comment: PLease share the mapping..

Comment: Thanks @Richa. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the field is a nested object, if I read the docs correctly then doc['field'] only supports simple term fields.

> Note, however, that the doc[...] notation only allows for simple valued fields (can’t return a json object from it) and makes sense only on non-analyzed or single term based fields.

However using _source has worked for me

```
   "script_fields" : {
      "field1" : {
           "script" : "_source.about.hobbies.size() > 0"
       }
    },
```

Comment: I think that simple valued fields, refer to the value, not to the field itself. So I don't think this is the problem here. _source is always an option, the thing is that it is much less efficient because this data is not found in memory, and need to be retrieved which is pretty expensive.